# phar exclude directories when creating tar archive

Tags: php, directory, tar, phar

I want to create a tar archive in a PHP script using the built-in `PharData` class.

I want the tar archive to represent a directory so I thought of using `PharData::buildFromDirectory()` to do that. Unfortunately the directory also is a git repository and has a `.git` folder in it which is much bigger than the directory itself.

So I need to remove that `.git` directory (ideally also the `.idea` directory...) from the archive because it would bloat it unnecessarily.

**What I tried so far:**

- Using a regular expression to filter the directory out:

  ```
  $archive->buildFromDirectory("..", "@^(?!.git).+@");
  ```

  Which didn't work.
- Using `PharData::delete()`, but unfortunately that seems to only delete a file and not a directory.

So, what is the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that the *full path* of the file gets matched, not only the directory (basename). Thus you cannot filter out the `.git` directory itself.

Using a character class negation (`[^.][^g][^i][^t]`) does also not help because there are parts of the path that do match this regex, so the path matches anyway.

This means you can use positive matches only.

---

You could use [Phar::buildFromIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromiterator.php) and then use  [RecursiveFilterIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php) to filter out the files. 
There you can define your own matching method that filters correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the following used to exclude git directories using a negative lookahead:

`$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__, '/^((?!\.git).)*$/');`